# Delete backup files according to rules

Tags: backup

I manage my backup files with homemade scripts:

- keep the 7 latest backups (full + incremental)
- keep the 5 latest full end-of-week full backups
- keep the 6 latest full end-of-month full backups
- those numbers are automatically higher if disk space allow it

So my scripts works. But I'm sure something already exists to manage this kind of need. Didn't found anything using Google.
Does anyone knows a (free as speech) software for that?

Comment: `rsnapshot` will do this.

Comment: ...or `backup2l`

Comment: I use `rsnapshot` too. There's also `rdiff-backup` which has similar ideas. They don't satisfy your "retain more if there's available disk space" requirement though.